# Powershell - How copy list of files to destination

Tags: powershell

I have a textfile (myfile.txt) that contains the source/destination of files to copy. For example....

```
c:\work\test1.txt \\server.usa.svr.com\sites\mysite\ztest1.txt
c:\work\test2.txt \\server.usa.svr.com\sites\mysite\ztest2.txt
c:\work\test3.txt \\server.usa.svr.com\sites\mysite\ztest3.txt
c:\work\test4.txt \\server.usa.svr.com\sites\mysite\ztest4.txt
c:\work\test5.txt \\server.usa.svr.com\sites\mysite\ztest5.txt
c:\work\test6.txt \\server.usa.svr.com\sites\mysite\ztest6.txt
```

Using powershell how can I open the file and copy from source to destination, for each file. Also, giving a status if error or success?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not quick and dirty? Replace c:\ with cp c:\, save as .ps1 and run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have spaces in file names (or they are properly quoted) you can try the following:

```
Import-Csv myfile.txt -Delimiter ' ' -Header Path,Destination | Copy-Item
```

You can pipe to `Copy-Item -WhatIf` first to see whether it's doing the right thing.